# How to Remove iOS dev/IDE/... from Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, disk-space

I need space in my SSD. I just need terminal tools in OS X El-capitan, not the Xcode IDE, not iOS, ... The space 10.49 Gb is just too much in my 60 GB disk partition. These PATHs do not work anymore so I cannot delete them

- `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/`
- `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`
- ...

---

How can you remove iOS/IDE/... from Xcode?

Comment: Could you just delete the entire program and then reinstall just the CLI tools. http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the Xcode app from `/Applications`, then delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`.

You can then install the command line tools separately, by downloading them from [Apple's Developer Downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (you'll need to log in with your Apple ID). The proper package is listed as "Command Line Tools (OS X version) for Xcode version". Obviously grab the one that applies to your current version of OS X.

Comment: That's the right package. I didn't add it to the edit since the image link was broken, but added a description of what to look for. That particular script is out of date, but my Github is https://github.com/robmathers and has that and other small projects.